# Typescript .sort() skips over a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given the array of numbers

```
let el = [25000,48000,57000,86000,33000,10000,42000,3000,54000,29000,79000,40000];
```

The output of the following suggests that it ignores the value of 3000

```
let el = [25000,48000,57000,86000,33000,10000,42000,3000,54000,29000,79000,40000];
console.log(el.sort());

//Output [10000, 25000, 29000,3000, 33000, 40000,42000, 48000, 54000,57000, 79000, 86000]
```

So it did sort, but didn't move the 3000 at the 4th position. Why is this happening?

Comment: `.sort()` without an argument will treat the values as strings and perform lexicographical sort. The result you get is correct for lexicographical sort: `"2" < "3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As VLAZ explained, By default, the sort() function sorts values as strings. if numbers are sorted as strings, "25" is bigger than "100", because "2" is bigger than "1".

Because of this, the sort() method will produce incorrect results when sorting numbers.

You can fix this by providing a compare function: `(a, b) => a - b)`

| compareFn(a, b) return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| `> 0` | sort `a` after `b` |
| `< 0` | sort `a` before `b` |
| `=== 0` | keep original order of `a` and `b` |

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description

e.g.

```js
let el = [25000,48000,57000,86000,33000,10000,42000,3000,54000,29000,79000,40000];
console.log(el.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```